# WPF C# Text box with hour string format

Tags: c#, wpf

How to make that user can only input hour format in text box for example HH:MM?

Comment: I'm not sure if a text box is the best control to use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on strictness of requirements you may want to create a specific behaviour that will be attached to `KeyDown` event and disable keys other than currently accepted given format and current text input position in (HH:MM), you could even think of different ways to guarantee automatic `:` input by your behaviour if you want to be limited by textbox control for time input.

you can get some inspiration here I think
[numeric only behaviour example](http://www.dataartist.net/blog/post/Silverlight-Behavior-Modifications-13-NumericOnlyBehavior.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Binding.StringFormat](http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/). It allows for conversion to `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` while specifying a certain string format to define how the user inputs the value, and how the value is displayed.

Comment: that's not what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a masked text box.

You can fine one on codeplex here...

[WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox&referringTitle=Home)

EDIT.
There is also a datetimeupdown control.  Which might be nearer to what you want.

Comment: limiting input to digit for example is not enough I think when we talk about HH:MM format. for HH you cannot input 3 in first H for example, for MM you cannot input 7 in first M .. If user was  limited to never be able to input 3_:__ in HH:MM format I dont think masked input is suitable ?

Comment: +1 good point but there is also a datetime control that might be suitable